# Injecting object through virtual type not working

Tags: magento2, di, virtualtype

I am using this config in di.xml

```
 <virtualType name="ourFirstVirtualType" type="Test\Testmod\Model\Newmodelclass">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="test_object" xsi:type="object">Test\Testmod\Model\Example2</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <type name="Test\Testmod\Model\Modelclass">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="the_object" xsi:type="object">ourFirstVirtualType</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

This is the Modelclass

```
<?php

namespace Test\Testmod\Model;
class Modelclass
{
    public $testProperty;
    public function __construct(Newmodelclass $the_object)
    {
        $this->testProperty = $the_object;
    }
}
```

and this is Newmodelclass

```
<?php

namespace Test\Testmod\Model;
class Newmodelclass
{
    public $newTestProperty;
    public function __construct(Againnewmodelclass $test_object)
    {
        $this->newTestProperty = $test_object;
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to test virtual type with this controller

```
<?php
namespace Test\Testmod\Controller\Index;

use Test\Testmod\Model\Modelclass;
use Test\Testmod\Model\Newmodelclass;
use Test\Testmod\Model\Againnewmodelclass;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        Modelclass $Modelclass,
        Newmodelclass $Newmodelclass,
        Againnewmodelclass $Againnewmodelclass
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->Modelclass = $Modelclass;
        $this->Newmodelclass = $Newmodelclass;
        $this->Againnewmodelclass = $Againnewmodelclass;
    }

    public function execute()
    {  
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($this->Modelclass);
        var_dump($this->Newmodelclass);
        var_dump($this->Againnewmodelclass);
        die;
    }

}
```

I think this should work correct right but giving this error instead

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Test\Testmod\Model\Newmodelclass::__construct() must be an instance of Test\Testmod\Model\Againnewmodelclass, 
>       instance of Test\Testmod\Model\Example2 given, called in /var/www/html/magento226/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111 
>       and defined in /var/www/html/magento226/app/code/Test/Testmod/Model/Newmodelclass.php:7

Answer (score 2):

Let's break down the dependency chain going from controller.

First argument is `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context` which is core object and will work as expected provided nothing has been altered.

The next argument that the DI will want to inject is `Modelclass $Modelclass`, which resolves to `Test\Testmod\Model\Modelclass` as defined in `use` statement. Now the DI will try to instantiate an object of this class. It will look at its constructor and will see there is 1 argument defined there, namely `Newmodelclass $the_object`. In regular situation where there is no additional configuration in `di.xml` this class would be resolved to `Test\Testmod\Model\Newmodelclass` by using the same namespace as there is no `use` statement.

However you have prepared a config in `di.xml` stating that `the_object` argument will be resolved to `ourFirstVirtualType`. So in this case DI will try to instantiate that and will resolve this name to `Test\Testmod\Model\Newmodelclass` as defined in `di.xml`. So far so good. We have correctly found the class to inject into `Test\Testmod\Model\Modelclass`.

Now DI will proceed to instantiating `Test\Testmod\Model\Newmodelclass` and it will read constructor argument of `$test_object` being locked at `Againnewmodelclass` (which by namespace is `Test\Testmod\Model\Againnewmodelclass`). However in `di.xml` you've defined that when instantiating virtual type of `ourFirstVirtualType` you want to pass as `test_object` argument class `Test\Testmod\Model\Example2`. This will then be used and the DI constructor will create an instance of `Test\Testmod\Model\Example2` and inject it to `Test\Testmod\Model\Newmodelclass`.

But here is a problem. To make it work `Test\Testmod\Model\Example2` must be of `Test\Testmod\Model\Againnewmodelclass` type or a descendant of it and in your case it seems it isn't. Either make `Test\Testmod\Model\Example2` a child of `Test\Testmod\Model\Againnewmodelclass` or change the constructor definition in `Test\Testmod\Model\Newmodelclass` to use an interface or a class type that will work with using `Test\Testmod\Model\Example2` as an argument.

Comment: I'm agree @Zefiryn, +1 for your answer